# clear interval to stop effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery [ripple effect](https://sirxemic.github.io/jquery.ripples/) on several background images to get the look of text under water.

To get what I want, I need to enable at least some 'perturbance.' Perturbance  is the amount of compounding/refracting among the ripples. Looks great initially, but it compounds continuously until the ripples go way beyond what I want.

I'm calling the ripples as follows:

```
$(".wavy").ripples({
    interactive:false,
    perturbance:0.01
});
```

And then adding them automatically like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
var $el = $(".wavy");
var x = Math.random() * $el.outerWidth();
var y = Math.random() * $el.outerHeight();
var dropRadius = 20;
var strength = 0.02 + Math.random() * 0.02;
$el.ripples('drop', x, y, dropRadius, strength);
}, 1000);
```

I need to stop the effect after a few seconds, so I'm trying to clear the interval or otherwise stop it after a certain  amount of time.

BTW, I first tried only running the effect when the headline is in the viewport, but both the 'pause' and 'destroy' methods for the effect were unacceptable. Pause stopped in the middle of the effect, and destroy made the background image (the headline) disappear.

To clear the interval, I tried this:

```
var wavyLength = setInterval(function() { myWavy () }, 400);

function myWavy() {
var $el = $(".wavy");
var x = Math.random() * $el.outerWidth();
var y = Math.random() * $el.outerHeight();
var dropRadius = 20;
var strength = 0.02 + Math.random() * 0.02;
$el.ripples('drop', x, y, dropRadius, strength);
}

clearInterval(wavyLength,10000);
```

But that made the ripple effect not run at all.

Trying to get better with JS. Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setTimeout` to wait `10000ms` then call `clearInterval`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(wavyLength)
}, 10000)
```

Comment: appreciate the help!